# Creating a password generator in c++ that saves the password in a .txt

Tags: c++, file, random, passwords, generator

Over the past day I have been creating a password generator that after generating a password gives you an option to save that password to a .txt file.

Everything is working except for the generating/printing the password in the Terminal and in the .txt file, after typing the length of the password, it generates it, but doesn't print.

Here is my code:

```
/* 
    Password generator by Yataga

    github.com/yataga

    twitter.com/yataga7

*/

#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    ofstream SavePass;
    char yn;
    const char TrueSelect = 'y';
    int SelectLengthInput;
    string pwd = "0aAbB1cCdD1eEf2F2gG3hHiIjJk3K45lLmM9n5N6o4OpPqQ76rRsStT78uUvVwW98xXyY0zZ";
    string password;
    cout << "Welcome to Yataga's random password generator" << endl;
    cout << "Type the size of yout random password" << endl;
    cin >> SelectLengthInput;
    cout << "generating your password....."<<endl;
    for(int i = 0; i<SelectLengthInput; i++) {
        password[i] = pwd[rand()%72];
    }
    cout<< "Your Password is: "<<password<<endl;
    cout<< "do you want to save this password in a file? (y/n): ";
    cin>>yn;
    if(yn == TrueSelect)
    {
        SavePass.open("passwords.txt");
        SavePass << password;
        SavePass.close();
        cout<< "Password saved on password.txt"<<endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout<< "Thanks for using my generator!";
    }
    return 0;   
}
```

Comment: `SavePass` should be [opened to append `std::ios::app`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ofstream/open) or you'll write over the contents of the file every time you open the file.

Answer (score 0):

Resize `password` before writing into it, like `password.resize(SelectLengthInput)`.

Also, input should be validated (e.g. what if the user enters -42?).

Also, saving could look like:

```
{
    ofstream SavePass("passwords.txt");
    SavePass << password;
    cout<< "Password saved on password.txt"<<endl;
} // SavePass is closed here automatically
```